# update tablesorter on dynamic table

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

i can't find the best way to update a table with dynamic data. the same table can change his data each time i toggle to a page with the table.

i tried `$('#table').trigger('destroy')` but then i get 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined'

i also tried

```
('#table').trigger('update')
```

and

```
 var sorting = [[1, 0]];
                    // $('#table').trigger('sorton', [sorting]);
                    // setTimeout(function () {
                    //     $('#table').trigger('sorton', [sorting]);
                    // }, 100);
```

nothing seems to work

my code : 
(after the table is ready )

```
$('#summary_table').tablesorter();
$('#summary_table').trigger('update');
var sorting = [[1, 0]];
setTimeout(function () {
    $('#summary_table').trigger('sorton', [sorting]);
}, 100);
```

Comment: The typical method to update the table is to trigger an "update". Since that isn't working for you, please share more information/code. Where is that update triggered? What do you mean by "toggle to a page with the table"? Is the table inside of tabs? Also, please include the files loaded (jQuery & other scripts).

Comment: i have a single page application. on the first div you have some links. each time you click on a link you toggle to a different div with ajax call to get the data. the table is build after i get the data from ajax. when you go back to the first div i want to destroy the table sorter so next time when you click on a link you will get the new table sorted.

Comment: ok, and some code would be helpful

Comment: i edited my question to see the code after the table is ready. i'm not writing the build code since it's too long

Answer (score 0):

To set an initial sort on a table while using tablesorter, set the [`sortList` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html#sortlist).

```
$(function(){
    $('#summary_table').tablesorter({
        sortList: [[1, 0]]
    });
});
```

The `sortList` link points to the documentation on my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html), which has lots of differences from the original tablesorter (v2.0.5b), but this method is the same.

Also, only use the "update" method if the content of the tbody has changed.

To make the table re-sort on the updated data, use the [`update` method](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html#update) resort variable:

```
// $("table").trigger("update", [resort, callback]);
// resort:
// [Boolean] true = resort using the already applied sort
// [Boolean] false = do not resort
// [Array]   Array similar to how the sortList option is set -> apply new sort
$("table").trigger("update", [ [[1, 0]], function(){
    // callback function called after update/sort completes
}] );
```

Comment: this is not working for me. the first table is sortable but when i go back and clean my table (with jquery empty) the second table isn't sortable

Comment: How is the table being emptied? If you want to replace the rows in the `tbody`, just replace them (no emptying required). If you are replacing the entire table, you'll need to reinitialize tablesorter.

Comment: what do you mean by replace? i must clear the table to append the new data. no?

Comment: I meant use `.html()` to replace the `tbody` content.

Comment: nothing seems to work.. the trigger('destroy') only work if i remove the widget-scroller plugin (and i want this plugin..) also, i remember that table sorter use to sort only th. on my table i have 3 rows of headers and only one of them suppose to be sortable. but now all 3 rows are triggering the sort.. not sure what to do anymore..

Comment: If you're using my fork, disable sorting of `th`'s by adding "sorter-false" class name to each. For the other issue, please modify [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/mqv16pd4/) showing the problem you are having.